# Splice method on JSONArray

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, splice

How can I 'cut' the actual array to get only the indexes that are higher than 10:

```
{ word: 's', count: 15 }
{ word: 'tesoro', count: 15 }
{ word: 'conceden', count: 15 }
{ word: 'determinadas', count: 15 }
{ word: 'interés', count: 15 }
{ word: 'cruz', count: 15 }
{ word: 't', count: 15 }
{ word: 'española', count: 15 }
{ word: 'establece', count: 15 }
{ word: 'ingeniería', count: 15 }
{ word: 'bienes', count: 15 }
{ word: 'renueva', count: 14 }
{ word: 'vigencia', count: 14 }
{ word: 'medidas', count: 14 }
{ word: 'san', count: 14 }
{ word: 'establecen', count: 14 }
{ word: 'transporte', count: 14 }
{ word: 'judicial', count: 14 }
{ word: 'agencia', count: 14 }
{ word: 'tribunal', count: 14 }
{ word: 'fabricados', count: 14 }
{ word: 'gran', count: 14 }
{ word: 'v', count: 14 }
{ word: 'artes', count: 13 }
{ word: 'entidades', count: 13 }
{ word: 'emplaza', count: 13 }
{ word: 'financiación', count: 13 }
{ word: 'interesados', count: 13 }
{ word: 'préstamos', count: 13 }
{ word: 'carta', count: 13 }
{ word: 'marina', count: 13 }
{ word: 'ambiente', count: 13 }
{ word: 'local', count: 13 }
{ word: 'sección', count: 13 }
{ word: 'valores', count: 13 }
{ word: 'julio', count: 13 }
{ word: 'temporal', count: 13 }
{ word: 'marco', count: 13 }
{ word: 'procedimiento', count: 13 }
{ word: 'gobierno', count: 13 }
{ word: 'como', count: 13 }
{ word: 'medio', count: 13 }
{ word: 'título', count: 12 }
{ word: 'ambiental', count: 12 }
{ word: 'no', count: 12 }
{ word: 'favor', count: 12 }
{ word: 'actividades', count: 12 }
{ word: 'relativo', count: 12 }
{ word: 'mercantil', count: 12 }
{ word: 'reino', count: 12 }
{ word: 'solar', count: 12 }
{ word: 'amparo', count: 12 }
{ word: 'convocatoria', count: 12 }
{ word: 'sociedad', count: 12 }
{ word: 'ejercicio', count: 12 }
{ word: 'cultural', count: 12 }
{ word: 'autoliquidación', count: 11 }
{ word: 'para', count: 11 }
{ word: 'acceso', count: 11 }
{ word: 'proyecto', count: 11 }
{ word: 'forma', count: 11 }
{ word: 'personal', count: 11 }
{ word: 'especial', count: 11 }
{ word: 'ts', count: 11 }
{ word: 'titulares', count: 11 }
{ word: 'impacto', count: 11 }
{ word: 'colaboración', count: 11 }
{ word: 'nagaterm', count: 11 }
{ word: 'música', count: 11 }
{ word: 'fondo', count: 11 }
{ word: 'curso', count: 11 }
{ word: 'acciones', count: 11 }
{ word: 'muebles', count: 11 }
{ word: 'hecho', count: 11 }
{ word: 'jus', count: 11 }
{ word: 'indulta', count: 10 }
{ word: 'cádiz', count: 10 }
{ word: 'fundaciones', count: 10 }
{ word: 'inscribe', count: 10 }
{ word: 'peñafort', count: 10 }
{ word: 'fomento', count: 10 }
{ word: 'raimundo', count: 10 }
{ word: 'ssi', count: 10 }
{ word: 'fundación', count: 10 }
{ word: 'carencia', count: 10 }
{ word: 'cursos', count: 10 }
{ word: 'mancha', count: 10 }
{ word: 'suscritos', count: 10 }
{ word: 'declaración', count: 10 }
{ word: 'reales', count: 10 }
{ word: 'castilla-', count: 10 }
{ word: 'decretos', count: 10 }
{ word: 'periodo', count: 10 }
{ word: 'protección', count: 10 }
{ word: 'coordinación', count: 10 }
{ word: 'regula', count: 10 }
{ word: 'incapacidad', count: 10 }
{ word: 'estatutos', count: 10 }
{ word: 'o', count: 10 }
{ word: 'carácter', count: 10 }
{ word: 'departamento', count: 10 }
{ word: 'de', count: 10 }
{ word: 'empresa', count: 10 }
{ word: 'kbb', count: 10 }
{ word: 'sin', count: 10 }
{ word: 'autonómica', count: 10 }
{ word: 'bilateral', count: 10 }
{ word: 'impartir', count: 10 }
{ word: 'subastas', count: 10 }
{ word: 'finca', count: 9 }
{ word: 'mercante', count: 9 }
{ word: 'éctrica', count: 9 }
{ word: 'conjunto', count: 9 }
{ word: 'enamel', count: 9 }
{ word: 'república', count: 9 }
{ word: 'k', count: 9 }
{ word: 'audiencia', count: 9 }
{ word: 'bien', count: 9 }
{ word: 'ámbito', count: 9 }
{ word: 'cultura', count: 9 }
{ word: 'obligaciones', count: 9 }
{ word: 'otorga', count: 9 }
{ word: 'español', count: 9 }
{ word: 'reconocimiento', count: 9 }
{ word: 'deportivas', count: 9 }
{ word: 'empresas', count: 9 }
{ word: 'presentación', count: 9 }
{ word: 'galicia', count: 9 }
{ word: 'junta', count: 9 }
{ word: 'ayuntamiento', count: 9 }
{ word: 'premios', count: 9 }
{ word: 'deportiva', count: 9 }
{ word: 'civil', count: 9 }
{ word: 'realización', count: 9 }
{ word: 'instalaciones', count: 9 }
{ word: 'sistemas', count: 9 }
{ word: 'rechaza', count: 8 }
{ word: 'premio', count: 8 }
{ word: 'migraciones', count: 8 }
{ word: 'expedir', count: 8 }
{ word: 'secundaria', count: 8 }
{ word: 'jubilación', count: 8 }
{ word: 'entidad', count: 8 }
{ word: 'escénicas', count: 8 }
{ word: 'comunicación', count: 8 }
{ word: 'municipal', count: 8 }
```

Is there any way to make a for loop and splice the array to get the final result of an array with only the elements where count >= 10 ?  Thanks!

Comment: arr.filter(function(a){return a.count>=10}) does it easier than a loop. if you want to mod the orig, gather a new one using this code, set origArr.length=0, then [].push.apply(origArr,arr); all that should be faster than running splice() a lot, which would re-build the array indexes each modification.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, if you want it to be compatible with old browsers as well as new, assuming your array is in a variable called `array`:

```
var result = [];
for( var i = 0, n = array.length;  i < n;  ++i ) {
    if( array[i].count > 10) {
        result.push( array[i] );
    }
}
```

Now `result` is an array with only the elements which have a `count` property greater than 10.

Comment: Thanks but i prefer the .filter() method. I don't want to use a lot of variables.

Comment: you can always drop-in [].filter, but you can't drop-in a way to recycle for-loop logic...

Comment: Sure, I like `.filter()` too, but it won't work in IE8 if that matters. Of course you can use a polyfill to provide your own `.filter()` method. But really we're talking about such a small piece of code here that it hardly matters how you implement it.